# Show Splash Screen & Progress Bar with Percentage using MVVM & WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm-light

I need to show Splash Screen  with Image & progress bar.

1. In  my application start up i have the  code as below to show the main window.

   ```
        SplashScreenWindowViewModel vm = new SplashScreenWindowViewModel(); 
        AutoResetEvent ev = new AutoResetEvent(false); 
         Thread uiThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
           vm.Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
           ev.Set();

           Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
           {
               SplashScreenWindow splashScreenWindow = new SplashScreenWindow();
               splashScreenWindow = new SplashScreenWindow();
               splashScreenWindow.Show();
               splashScreenWindow.DataContext = vm;
               vm.InstigateWorkCommand.Execute(null);

           });

           Dispatcher.Run();
       });
         uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
         uiThread.IsBackground = true;
         uiThread.Start();
         ev.WaitOne();
   ```
2. In my main viewmodel i have code as below

   class  MainviewModel : viewmodelbase
   {
     rivate string _message;
           private object content;
           private readonly BackgroundWorker worker; 
           private readonly ICommand instigateWorkCommand;

   ```
       public SplashScreenWindowViewModel()
       {

           this.instigateWorkCommand = new
            RelayCommand(() => this.worker.RunWorkerAsync(), () => !this.worker.IsBusy);
           this.worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };           
           this.worker.DoWork += this.DoWork;
           this.worker.ProgressChanged += this.ProgressChanged;
           _message = "0 % completed";

       }



       public ICommand InstigateWorkCommand
       {

           get { return this.instigateWorkCommand; }
       }

       private double _currentProgress;
       public double CurrentProgress        
       {
           get { return this._currentProgress; }
           set
           {
               if (this._currentProgress != value)
               {

                   this._currentProgress = value;                   
                   RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");
               }
           }
       }
       private int _progressMax;
       public int ProgressMax
       {
           get { return this._progressMax; }

           set
           {
               if(this._progressMax != value)
               {
                 this._progressMax = value;
                 RaisePropertyChanged("ProgressMax");
               }

           }
       }

       private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
       {
         this.CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;


       }

       private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
       {

          // calling my long running operation
          DAL.dotimeconsumingcode();
          worker.ReportProgress((int)e.argument);

       }




       public string Message
       {
           get
           {
               return _message;
           }
           set
           {
               if (Message == value) return;
               _message = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("Message");
           }
       }


       public object Content
       {
           get
           {
               return content;
           }
           set
           {
               if (Content == value) return;
               content = value;

               RaisePropertyChanged("Content");
           }
       }

       public Dispatcher Dispatcher
       {
           get;
           set;
       }
   ```

   }

   MY UI has  one user control with progress bar and one splash main window.
   when my long running operation is completed , my Main window(main application) is opened.
   //User Control

   ```
           <ProgressBar Height="27" Value="{Binding CurrentProgress, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Margin="53,162,57,0" Name="progressBar"  Grid.Row="1"
                Maximum="{Binding Path=ProgressMax, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"    Visibility="{Binding ProgressVisibility}"  />
   ```

   //SplashWindow

   ```
     <localView:usercontrol/>
   ```

My Problem is

ProgressChangedevent is not firing and % completion is not showing up in the text block either.  Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not registered a complete handler and you are not calling progress properly.
This sample from MSDN covers it all.

[BackGroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: Hi Blam  in my mainviewmodel constructor i have registered for all the event handlers. the only thing missing was   backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted. Done that but no Progress.

Comment: Not clear.  So complete is working?   Did you fix the call to progress?  Please update the question with the current code.